# Check Checkbox on Intranet Page VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

i have been trying to automate the checking of over 400 checkboxes on an internal page. i beleive i have located the code of one of the buttons but am unable to get this to work.

```
    <INPUT type="checkbox" name=PrincipalId class="padding-right: 15px;padding-top: 0px;padding- 
bottom: 0px"
value="585"
 title="JohnSmith"
onClick="document.getElementById('idSelectAll').checked=false;" >
<INPUT type="hidden"   name=PrincipalName
value="Smith%2C%20John%20%28Senior%20Manager%29" >
</td><td class="ms-vb2">
```

Comment: Is this a one time thing or is this needed lots of times? I would probably solve it by doing `Tab` `Space` `Tab` and so on, with some automation. You can use VBA if you manage to switch to the browser window and use sendkeys

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it would be repeated x 400. What you suggested is what i was previously using but using sendkeys but i am not happy with this approach as it is time consuming not failproof and also means i cannot interact with other applications are running, hence the reason for trying to take another approach. ideally i'm hoping that by somehow getting the 1st 400 checkboxes on the page to check in one line of code or loop through each with the getelements syntax with the added exclusion for 2 checkbox values.

Comment: If you have to select all checkboxes on the page, you can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all checkboxes on the page, then loop through to select them

Comment: this is what i have tried but i get an error.   IE.document.getElementsByTagName ("checkbox")
For Each e In elems
    If (e.getAttribute("value") > 0) Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next e

Comment: still stuck on this one I think the checkboxes are within  a frame or held within a table but I am unable to obtain the id's/names for any of this as my html knowledge is limited.